# Why time format and parse gives different results?

Tags: parsing, go, time, format

I'm taking the current time and format it and parse it back. When I compare the result with the current time they are not equal.

Here is a playground example:
https://play.golang.org/p/DDFzi1t8v_-

```
t := time.Now()
formatted := t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000 -0700")
parsed, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000 -0700", formatted)
fmt.Println(parsed.Equal(t))
```

This is working on the playground but not in my local computer because my timezone is +0300.

Here is the output of the same code on my computer:

```
t         :  2018-03-09 13:38:37.229832 +0300 +03 m=+0.000440904
formatted :  2018-03-09 13:38:37.229 +0300
parsed    :  2018-03-09 13:38:37.229 +0300 +03
false
```

How can I make them equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is on the precision of the date.

Your `time.Now()` returns a result with 6 decimals (Microseconds) and you try to format a time with 3 decimals (Milliseconds).

You have to Round your time at Milliseconds like that :

```
t := time.Now().Round(time.Millisecond)
```